# How to move to different tabs in a webpage using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, html

I have a scenario where I need to click a tab and enter some text and come back to first tab.

Assuming there are three tabs on page, How do i move to tab2 or tab3 and come back to tab1.

NOTE: I am just talking about tabs, Not windows. I tried all sorts findElement (webdriver's) methods, but no luck.    By default i will be on ABSENCE (ie when page first loads). I have to move to EXCEPTIONS tab

I am using java as a code language.

please see below code (TWO HTML TABS: 1) Absence 2) Exceptions). You can see tab name in span tab's.

```
<td nowrap="nowrap" align="center">
    <a accesskey="A" title="Absence" href="javascript:submitAction_RBET (document.win0,'TAB_BUTTON_ID','TIMESHEET#D');" name="TIMESHEET#D" tabindex="784">
       <span>
          <label class="PTUNDERLINE">A</label> bsence
       </span>
    </a>
</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" align="center">
    <a accesskey="E" title="Exceptions" href="javascript:submitAction_RBET(document.win0,'TAB_BUTTON_ID','TIMESHEET#E');" name="TIMESHEET#E" tabindex="784">
       <span>
          <label class="PTUNDERLINE">E</label> xceptions
       </span>
    </a>
</td>
```

Comment: The tab must have a link or other element that you click in order to access it. Which Selenium WebDriver are you using?

Comment: i am using webdriver 2. And I have used element locators such as: By.name, By.classname and By.ID.And pretty much i tried all sorts of element findings to locate the tab and click , but no luck.

Comment: Is this a browser tab or html based tabs on the same web page?

Comment: OK what is the element that you click on to change tabs?

Comment: By default i will be on ABSENCE (ie when page first loads). I have to move to EXCEPTIONS tab.

Comment: Why not just `webdriver.findElement(By.name("TIMESHEET#E")).click()`?

Comment: @ross: I have tried what you suggested. But no luck.Adding to the above I like to say that above code comes in tag called FORM. please see below. May be this might help to figure out solution for my problem.

Comment: <form class="PSForm" autocomplete="off" action="http://slc00zhs.us.XYX.com:8000/psc/sxyzlc/EMPLOYEE/HCM/c/ROLE_EMPLOYEE.TL_MSS_EE_SRCH_PRD.GBL" method="post" name="win0">

Comment: i am assuming that swtiching to frame can be applied here. I have tried swtichto.frame(..),  Still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I used below solution to switch over between the tabs.

```
     new Actions(driver)
    .sendKeys(driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")), Keys.CONTROL)
    .sendKeys(driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")), Keys.NUMPAD2)
    .build().perform();
```

In above `Keys.NUMPAD2` refers that you are gonna move to the second tab in the session.
You can move to Third, Fourth, etc... by giving NUMPAD3, NUMPAD4, etc... respectively.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: the above couldn't do the job.

Comment: Did it throw any error? Just ensure manually the shortcut is working fine in your box?

Comment: It doesnt throw any exception. What is the purpose of "tagName=html" ?. I am assuming your code deals with the content in between <html> and </html> . You are expecting "numpad2", "numpad3" and other tabs to be found since these are inside html tags (ie. <html>) ,if that is true then I can assure you, it doesnt find the tabs that i am looking for or any tabs on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I have a pretty hacky solution. I was in a similar situation and got around this problem by opening all of the tabs in a new window, by shift-clicking (This was on a Mac so the shortcut might be different on different platforms). It looks something like this:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver); 
Action holdShift = builder.keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).build();
holdShift.perform();
webElement.click();

new Actions(driver).keyUp(Keys.SHIFT).build().perform();
//do something with window handles/names here (can switch between these).
```

Comment: OP said "tab", but he doesn't mean a browser-tab, they mean something inside the page that looks like a tab. So while you're right about opening in windows instead of browser-tabs, it's not the answer they're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Can you put an id on the a tag?

```
<a id="tab1"></a>
```

then use

```
WebElement tab1 = driver.findElement(By.id("tab1"));
tab1.click();
```

And if you can't then you have other options:

http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html

XPath would work but I can't say I like writing xpath expressions so I would try css selector. See http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp
Something like this (although this is quite brittle)

```
By.cssSelector("[title=Absence]");
```

Comment: What you said is right for the person who is writing html code. In my case I am not HTML developer I am just tester and I dont have previlages to change source code.